# How to make parameter name in URL default and hidden in Kohana?

Tags: php, routes, kohana

I'm trying to make this work. I want my routing to behave like this:
when I type URL ie. `example.com/api/getpage/http://smth.com` I want to retrieve in my action `id` parameter with `http://smth.com` value.
My routing for this case looks like this right now:

```
Route::set('api', 'api/<action>/<id>')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'api',
        'action'     => 'index'
    ));
```

And what's in action:

```
public function action_getpage()
    {
        $obj = $this->scrape($this->request->query('id'));
        $this->response->body(json_encode($obj));
    }
```

Now URL like this `example.com/api/getpage?id=http://smth.com` works like a charm, but I don't want it that way. Is there any way to achieve that goal? Thanks in advance for all suggestions.

Comment: Why dont use query params?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you can't use slashes within a url segment (except in get parameters).  This has nothing to do with kohana routing but how your web server handles it.  The only way around it would be to replace he slashes with something else.  You'd also encounter issues if the url you pass as the final segment had get parameters on the end of it,  the question mark would be cause it to be treated as get parameters of your main url, not the final segments.

Another option would be to base64 encode the final url segment then decode it inside your controller.  This would get rid of any slashes and question marks.  Php has simple base64_encode and base64_decode functions.  The only downside is tha portion of the url will look like an arbitrary garbled string.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php